# Is $f$ a non zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Consider the ring $R=\dfrac {k[x,y,z,t]}{(y(xt-yz))}$. Consider the polynomial $f=t(yz-xt)$. Is $f$ a non zero divisor of $R$?

I think the answer is yes, because if $f$ is zero divisor then $fh=y(yz-xt)k$ for some polynomials $h$ and $k$. How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a zero divisor of $R$, since $-yf = (y(xt-yz))t = 0t = 0$.

Comment: @Arthur,@McFry, Thanks but what about the polynomial $t(y^3-x^2z)$ ?

Comment: However, something is missing: $-y\ne0$ in the factor ring.